# How to generate In-Memory pptx file using python-pptx in flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-pptx

i'm trying to generate the in-memory `ppt` file without using file system in my `flask` app by using `python-pptx` package. I've already referred to the [documentation](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html) and I'm trying to replicate another example but it's not working as expected.

Here is my code:

```
import io   
from pptx import Presentation

from flask import send_file,..

@app.route('/ppt', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def genppt():
    testfile = StringIO()      
    prs = Presentation()
    title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
    title = slide.shapes.title
    subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]
    title.text = "Hello, World!"
    subtitle.text = "python-pptx was here!"    
    prs.save(testfile)
    return send_file(testfile,attachment_filename='test.pptx', as_attachment=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using the wrong `io` type, refer to this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

instead of `testfile = StringIO()` use `testfile = io.BytesIO()`

and don't forget to force the right `mimetype` parameter in `send_file()` since you want to send `.pptx` (Microsoft PowerPoint (OpenXML)) and not `.ppt` (Microsoft PowerPoint),

```
[..]
    return send_file(testfile,
                     attachment_filename="test.pptx",
                     mimetype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", # here
                     as_attachment=True)
```

refer to the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Comment: i've tried with BytesIO as well. but it's generating the blank pptx.
@app.route('/ppt', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def genppt():
    testfile = BytesIO()      
    prs = Presentation()
    title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
    #Above code     
    prs.save(testfile)
    return send_file(testfile,  attachment_filename="testing.pptx",                     mimetype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",                      as_attachment=True)

Comment: just i want to make sure, your script is now working but it sends (download) an empty .pptx file ?

Comment: yes correct. downloaded pptx is blank and data is not getting added into slides.

Comment: i have no previous experience with `python-pptx` but i've looked at the doc and it seems they have putted some good snippets. your code SHOULD work. it's similar to the `Hello World` example i guess.

Comment: Yes you are correct. but it's not working :(. instead of using filesystem i'm trying to utilize in-memory pptx creation.

Comment: what kind of errors ? share error stack so i can help you

Comment: sorry. no issues with code. but, the title.text is not inserting the 'hello world' into pptx. need to fix that.

Comment: Try adding the line: `testfile.seek(0)` after the `prs.save()` call and before the `send_file()` call. The file-position pointer of the `io.BytesIO` object will be at the end of the file after writing, and if `send_file()` starts reading from there it will be blank (zero bytes).